# How to set up imported multiple times rule for date-fns in eslint?

Tags: eslint, date-fns

I am using import of `date-fns` functions like this:

```
import addHours from 'date-fns/addHours';
import addDays from 'date-fns/addDays';
```

But also I am getting an error from eslint:
`node_modules/date-fns/typings.d.ts' imported multiple times.eslintimport/no-duplicates`

What is wrong? It is not multiple import, I am importing from different level.

How can I fix it without disable multiple import rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a know issue with `date-fns` library

Here are the issues

1. [[Typescript] I can't import the translation (locale) of the terms in typescript.](https://gitmemory.com/issue/date-fns/date-fns/1756/624803874)
2. [Is there any good way to import locale and other function within one line?](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/1677)

Comment: Do you know how to  bypass date-fns in this situation? What's the best approach nowadays